Squareup Node SDK location filtering doesnt filter item variations
Using the Square node SDK, I have two locations setup a physical store and an online one. A subset of all the products are marked as available at both locations. Some item variations are marked as available at only the physical store.
When searching catalog items and filtering by the enabled locations the correct products are returned however item variations within a product are still returned even though they are not available in the filtered location.
L66QCWSEXGERR
Example request:
const response = await client.catalogApi.searchCatalogItems({
  enabledLocationIds: ["L66QCWSEXGERR"],
  sortOrder: "ASC",
});

Example response:
{
  "type": "ITEM",
  "id": "BYGY64ETQO7ZUTSQH7RZYZKG",
  "updated_at": "2024-06-22T16:02:39.386Z",
  "created_at": "2017-11-28T22:34:33.261Z",
  "version": 1719072159386,
  "is_deleted": false,
  "present_at_all_locations": false,
  "present_at_location_ids": [
    "57AT16DDBM3T0",
    "L66QCWSEXGERR"
  ],
  "item_data": {
    "name": "Battered",
    "label_color": "E5457A",
    "is_taxable": true,
    "visibility": "PRIVATE",
    "available_online": false,
    "available_for_pickup": false,
    "available_electronically": false,
    "tax_ids": [
      "UIOLOOAZMKN6KLD7LVCTPT7N"
    ],
    "variations": [
      {
        "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
        "id": "4HAG6P4P6G3AXZUVHC6LZAOP",
        "updated_at": "2024-06-22T15:58:50.312Z",
        "created_at": "2017-11-28T23:01:23.228Z",
        "version": 1719071930312,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "present_at_all_locations": false,
        "present_at_location_ids": [
          "57AT16DDBM3T0",
          "L66QCWSEXGERR"
        ],
        "item_variation_data": {
          "item_id": "BYGY64ETQO7ZUTSQH7RZYZKG",
          "name": "Jumbo",
          "ordinal": 1,
          "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
          "price_money": {
            "amount": 280,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "location_overrides": [
            {
              "location_id": "57AT16DDBM3T0",
              "track_inventory": false
            }
          ],
          "service_duration": 0,
          "sellable": true,
          "stockable": true,
          "channels": [
            "CH_gLYbTcdeSdE6b9e4SMGRpyS2Ynpt5OE1XIcUbRlQuYC"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
        "id": "U6U7QD4AWJ5BXMGF5ORTD65Y",
        "updated_at": "2024-06-22T16:02:39.386Z",
        "created_at": "2017-11-28T23:01:23.228Z",
        "version": 1719072159386,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "present_at_all_locations": false,
        "present_at_location_ids": [
          "57AT16DDBM3T0",
          "L66QCWSEXGERR"
        ],
        "item_variation_data": {
          "item_id": "BYGY64ETQO7ZUTSQH7RZYZKG",
          "name": "Small",
          "ordinal": 2,
          "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
          "price_money": {
            "amount": 195,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "location_overrides": [
            {
              "location_id": "57AT16DDBM3T0"
            },
            {
              "location_id": "L66QCWSEXGERR"
            }
          ],
          "track_inventory": false,
          "service_duration": 0,
          "sellable": true,
          "stockable": true,
          "channels": [
            "CH_gLYbTcdeSdE6b9e4SMGRpyS2Ynpt5OE1XIcUbRlQuYC"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
        "id": "LDIXLEPK65WPPDOD5HXSQKI7",
        "updated_at": "2024-06-22T16:02:39.386Z",
        "created_at": "2022-09-01T12:30:08.274Z",
        "version": 1719072159386,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "present_at_all_locations": false,
        "present_at_location_ids": [
          "57AT16DDBM3T0"
        ],
        "item_variation_data": {
          "item_id": "BYGY64ETQO7ZUTSQH7RZYZKG",
          "name": "Jumbo special",
          "ordinal": 3,
          "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
          "price_money": {
            "amount": 400,
            "currency": "GBP"
          },
          "location_overrides": [
            {
              "location_id": "57AT16DDBM3T0",
              "track_inventory": false
            },
            {
              "location_id": "L66QCWSEXGERR",
              "track_inventory": false
            }
          ],
          "track_inventory": false,
          "service_duration": 0,
          "sellable": true,
          "stockable": true,
          "channels": [
            "CH_gLYbTcdeSdE6b9e4SMGRpyS2Ynpt5OE1XIcUbRlQuYC"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "product_type": "REGULAR",
    "skip_modifier_screen": false,
    "ecom_uri": "https://scotts-fish-chips.square.site/product/battered/20",
    "ecom_available": true,
    "ecom_visibility": "VISIBLE",
    "pickup_fulfillment_preferences_id": "fprefs_127djcswkee7q8gvs6gjjf0xy",
    "delivery_fulfillment_preferences_id": "fprefs_127djcswjocukqk5u6orzcnly",
    "channels": [
      "CH_gLYbTcdeSdE6b9e4SMGRpyS2Ynpt5OE1XIcUbRlQuYC"
    ],
    "shipping_fulfillment_preferences_id": "fprefs_1281alfdwusi1vvoms9rb8mvr",
    "dine_in_fulfillment_preferences_id": "fprefs_127n3dg94obvw23to921gkbet",
    "is_archived": false
  }
},

Notice how item variation with the ID: LDIXLEPK65WPPDOD5HXSQKI7 isn't available at the filtered location but is still returned in the response.
